# Google Chrome. Removing items form context menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is that possible: remove some context's elements?
I dont want remove core items, but if i will able to remove or disable some things which added by extensions, it will be nice.

Comment: Why do you feel your website should be allowed to override the behaviour of extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove some elements added by other extension from your extension, what you can do is to [disable](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-setEnabled) them (you will need `management` permission for that). There is no way to be more specific than that and disable only some parts of other extensions, sorry.